# How can you find the $u$ using time dilation if you only know $\Delta t_o$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, spacetime, speed-of-light, time-dilation

I've come across two problems dealing with time dilation now that ask how fast should an astronaut go in order to travel EG: 400 LYears in 10 Years.

What I can not wrap my head around is how this is solvable if time dilation has three variables : $\Delta t$,  $\Delta t_o$, and  $u$

($\Delta t = \Delta t_o / (1 - (u/c)^2))$

The answers I have found online assume that $\Delta t$ is not only known, but that, in the above mentioned example, is 400 years. That says that to a stationary observer the astronaut is moving at the speed of light - but isn't the point that we are trying to discern what speed he is moving at?

How is it possible that we know $\Delta t$ - or is there actually a different method that should be applied to solving this problem?

---

Its not really as simple as setting $\Delta t$ = d/$u$ is it?

Comment: If $v$ is the velocity in Earth frame then the time in the Earth frame is $d/v$, and the time in the astronauts frame is therefore $(d/v)\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$. Set this equal to 10 years and solve for $v$.

Comment: So it is as easy as setting Δt = d/u. Thank you @JohnRennie.